# How to get constructor arguments name in attributes with .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

Here is the code :

I'm looking for a way to access arguments value by name.

The attribute is like this :

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Field)]
public class EDataAttrAttribute : Attribute {

    public EDataAttrAttribute(int GroupID, int MinimumPermissionToEdit, bool ForcePersianLetter = false) {
        this.GroupID = GroupID;
        this.MinimumPermissionToEdit = MinimumPermissionToEdit; 
    }


    public int GroupID { get; private set; }
    public int MinimumPermissionToEdit { get; private set; } 

}
```

---

```
public class EUser {
    [EDataAttr(1, 1)]
    public string FirstName;
}
```

---

```
                    var attr = typeof(T).GetField("FirstName").CustomAttributes.FirstOrDefault(a => a.AttributeType == typeof(EDataAttrAttribute));
                    int n = attr.ConstructorArguments.Count; // 2 !
                    int v = attr.NamedArguments.Count;       // 0 !
```

How to get MinimumPermissionToEdit value while you don't know index int.
I know only it's named MinimumPermissionToEdit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use LINQ for this. Additionally, you will have to use the [`NamedArguments`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.customattributedata.namedarguments.aspx) property instead of `ConstructorArguments`:

```
NamedArguments.Single(x => x.MemberName == "Name").Value
```

However, for `NamedArguments` to work, you actually have to use the names when using the attribute. Your updated code shows that you don't do this.

In that case, there is no way to get the value by name. You just have to use the index. Contrary to what you say, the index *is well known*. It is the index it occurs in the constructor. `MinimumPermissionToEdit` occurs at the second position, so its index is 1.

Comment: This return no data while I have three properties in my attribute.

Comment: @Mahdi: As Jon said, please show us how you *use* that attribute. You updated your code with the declaration of the attributes class, not with its usage.

Comment: Can you please let me know how to use Name on my attributes ?

Comment: @Mahdi: `[EDataAttr(GroupID = 1, MinimumPermissionToEdit = 1)]`

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`NamedArguments`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.customattributedata.namedarguments.aspx) to access those; the [`MemberInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.customattributenamedargument.memberinfo.aspx) property on `CustomAttributeNamedArgument` allows you to reflect on the member that would be set using a named attribute argument.

Comment: This return no data while I have three properties in my attribute.

Comment: @Mahdi: Show us how you are instantiating the attribute.