# How to get constructor named arguments from attribute

Tags: c#, reflection, arguments

I have the same problem as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15922236/how-to-get-constructor-arguments-name-in-attributes-with-net). The problem is that, even when using named arguments in the attribute's constructor, I still get an empty collection.

This is my Attribute definition:

```
public class MenuItemAttribute : Attribute
{
    ApplicationCategoryEnum ApplicationCategory { get; }
    string ControllerDisplayName { get; }
    bool IsDefaultRoute { get; }

    public MenuItemAttribute(ApplicationCategoryEnum applicationCategory, string controllerDisplayName, bool isDefaultRoute)
    {
        ControllerDisplayName = controllerDisplayName;
        ApplicationCategory = applicationCategory;
        IsDefaultRoute = isDefaultRoute;
    }
}
```

and this is how I use it:

```
[MenuItem(
    applicationCategory: ApplicationCategoryEnum.CONTROLPANEL,
    controllerDisplayName: "Account Management",
    isDefaultRoute: false)]
public class AccountController : Controller { /// }
```

This is how I get through the Controller's attributes:

```
var attributeData = controllerInfo
    .CustomAttributes
    .FirstOrDefault(attrs => attrs.AttributeType == typeof(MenuItemAttribute))
    .NamedArguments;
```

Arguments are there as I can see them if I use `ConstructorArguments` instead of `NamedArguments`.

What am I missing?

Comment: Does attribute's properties should not be public?

Comment: @Miamy it isn't technically required

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently all your parameters are positional ones, so they are returned in `ConstructorArguments`.

As written in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/attributes#positional-and-named-parameters):

> Each non-static public read-write field and property for an attribute class defines a named parameter for the attribute class.

Changing your `MenuItemAttribute` to for example:

```
    public class MenuItemAttribute : Attribute
    {
        ApplicationCategoryEnum ApplicationCategory { get; }
        public string ControllerDisplayName { get; set; }
        public bool IsDefaultRoute { get; set; }

        public MenuItemAttribute(ApplicationCategoryEnum applicationCategory)
        {
            ApplicationCategory = applicationCategory;
        }
    }
```

And usage

```
[MenuItem(ApplicationCategoryEnum.CONTROLPANEL, ControllerDisplayName = "asdsa", IsDefaultRoute = true)]
```

Will give you 2 elements in `NamedArguments` collection.

Answer (score 3):

The syntax:

```cs
[MenuItem(
    applicationCategory: ApplicationCategoryEnum.CONTROLPANEL,
    controllerDisplayName: "Account Management",
    isDefaultRoute: false)]
```

represents *constructor* arguments; the data you want is in the `ConstructorArguments` member:

```cs
var attrib = typeof(AccountController)
    .CustomAttributes
    .FirstOrDefault(attrs => attrs.AttributeType == typeof(MenuItemAttribute));
if (attrib is object)
{
    var declared = attrib.Constructor.GetParameters();
    var values = attrib.ConstructorArguments;
    for (int i = 0; i < values.Count; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{declared[i].Name}={values[i].Value}");
    }
}
```

(`NamedArguments` are for the ever-so-subtly-different usage involving `=`, i.e. `IsDefaultRoute = true` invokes the property-setter of the `IsDefaultRoute` property with the value `true`)

Comment: So you can't access parameter name and parameter value from the same object?

Comment: @DavideVitali no; the API knows that the parameter names are available from the `.Constructor`, so it makes no attempt to duplicate that information for you; ultimately, the constructor arguments aren't actually set by name - they're set by position (the C# compiler moves them around as needed before baking the metadata)

Comment: @DavideVitali you can see this in more detail [in this example](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghgzgLgpgJwDQxASwDYB8DaABARgDoBhAezAAcyA7OGmAWTIBM4MiAhBMgdygjAMcABTAe/QcJAACAGYQMUOAEoAugFgAUHgDMMvACYZJGQG8AvkA==) which shows the actual IL - no arg names, just types a raw dump of binary that can be interpreted as the values